# How can probability be used to make a prediction, using the Titanic dataset as an example?

Tags: probability

I'm new to machine learning and data science, and I have a question I'm not sure how else to find the answer for. I'll use a simplified example of the Titanic dataset to illustrate the problem.

In this scenario 200 people are on a boat which sinks. We have certain details about 100 of them, including their gender and whether or not they survived. We have have the same info on the other 100, but we don't know whether they survived or not. We have to predict that.

Of the 100 we have the most data on, we know that 70 were male and 30 were female. We also know that 80% of those females survived and only 5% of those males survived.

If we make a prediction that each person from the second dataset (the 100 whose survival is unknown) died, we can get a pretty high number of correct predictions (assuming they follow the same trends as the first 100).

We can get an even higher degree of accuracy by simply predicting that all males died and all females lived.

By including other features in our probability calculation we notice that, for example, male children in first class were significantly more likely to survive than elderly men in third class. If we see that certain groups of males had a near 100% likelihood of survival, we can safely adjust our prediction to say "All females survived and all males died EXCEPT for this group of males, who also survived".

However, what if we're only 90% sure they survived, or 60% sure?

So my question is, how can I calculate at what point an individual male's likelihood of survival become high enough that a prediction should go against the gender-based prediction? I understand how to use Bayes theorem to calculate any random male's likelihood of survival, but how can I calculate the cut-off between predicting he dies and predicting he lives? Is the cut-off 50%? Is it the same as the overall survival rate (around 28% in this case)? Something else? Thanks.

Comment: `We can get an even higher degree of accuracy by simply predicting that all males died and all females lived.` this is called the class imbalance problem and is an issue for alot of classification problems in the real world i.e. fraud, retail etc.